# When I create a Calendar instance the first day of the month = 2

Tags: java, android

When I get an instance of Calendar, the first day of the month should be 1 according to the docs.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

It prints "1367366400", which is the timestamp for "04 / 30 / 13", the last day of the previous month.

I could set it to "2" and use it like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 32; i++) {
```

But that just looks odd!
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you determine that 1367366400 is the timestamp for "04 / 30 / 13"?

Comment: I used http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm and it gave me a date of Wed, 01 May 2013 00:00:00 GMT. Perhaps you've used a method that presents a local time in a different timezone?

Comment: You're correct, it must have been the unixtime converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing time in millis and converting to check , print the day, year and month like this :

```
    System.out.println("Year: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("Month: " + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
    System.out.println("Days: " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

I suppose your code is fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks to this I figured the problem lays somewhere else.